# Choose UIlabel background Color from Array and then remove it from array. (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uicolor, uibackgroundcolor

I have 3 UiLabels onscreen. I have an array with colors e.g. red,green,blue. I want to set the background of each UiLabel to a a color in the array and then delete the Color from the array so no 2 UiLabels have the same Color.

I was trying to do something like this. it selects a random string in the array but then i cannot assign it to the uilabel because its not of type UIColor.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let Colorarray = ["UIColor.redColor()", "UIColor.greenColor()", "UIColor.blueColor()"]


    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Colorarray.count)))


    print(randomIndex)
    self.left.text = (Colorarray[randomIndex])


    self.left.backgroundColor =  (Colorarray[randomIndex])
    self.middle.backgroundColor = (Colorarray[randomIndex])
    self.right.backgroundColor = (Colorarray[randomIndex])



}
```

this was the second code i tried

var colorArray = [(UIColor.redColor(), "Red"), (UIColor.greenColor(), "Green"), (UIColor.blueColor(), "Blue")]

```
//random color
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colorArray.count)))

//accessing color
var (color, name) = colorArray[randomIndex]
self.left.text = name
self.left.backgroundColor = color
let leftColorRemoval = (colorArray.removeAtIndex(randomIndex))
print(leftColorRemoval)

var (mcolor, mname) = colorArray[randomIndex]
self.middle.text = mname
self.middle.backgroundColor = mcolor
let middleColorRemoval = (colorArray.removeAtIndex(randomIndex))
print(middleColorRemoval)

var (rcolor, rname) = colorArray[randomIndex]
self.right.text = rname
self.right.backgroundColor = rcolor
let rightColorRemoval = (colorArray.removeAtIndex(randomIndex))
print(rightColorRemoval)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store an array of tuples that include both the actual `UIColor` and the string value. This makes it so you can provide any string value you want:

```
let colorArray = [(UIColor.redColor(), "Red"), (UIColor.greenColor(), "Green"), (UIColor.blueColor(), "Blue")]
```

Then, to access a random color:

```
let (color, name) = colorArray[randomIndex]

self.left.text = name

self.left.backgroundColor = color
...
```

It seems to me that your code doesn't actually remove random colors. Here's how you would actually do it (one of many ways):

```
let random = { () -> Int in
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colorArray.count)))
} // makes random number, you can make it more reusable

let (leftColor, leftName) = colorArray.removeAtIndex(random()) // removeAtIndex: returns the removed tuple
let (middleColor, middleName) = colorArray.removeAtIndex(random())
let (rightColor, rightName) = colorArray.removeAtIndex(random())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, using the tuples seems to work well in donating colors. was playing around with the code in order to try and make sure removal of the previously donated color so there would be no color occurring twice onscreen, i came up with this but there are intermittent failures of the code for some reason. it will only work about 1 in 4 times.

Comment: see below i couldn't add it in comments haha

Comment: @PeterGaffney 1. Remove that answer's code and add it into your question as an edit so it doesn't get flagged. 2. The reason for the randomness not working is that it isn't getting a new index each time. See how my code calls `random()` each time?

Comment: Thats brilliant got it to work with your code just started. thanks man :)